# Node application does not restart though strong pm is running

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

We are using loopback to our node application using strong-pm as service on a production server. I used the following commands to run the application.

```
/sbin/initctl start strong-pm

/sbin/initctl status strong-pm

slc start

slc ctl set-size myapp 20
```

When node breaks, it does not restart and I need to run `slc start` again. Am I missing something here?

Comment: `slc start` is meant to be a dev tool, not a deployment tool. If you use `slc deploy` instead, it should restart automatically for you.

Comment: can you help me further with slc deploy. We do not use git.. I stopped existing service with slc ctl stop my service and then run slc deploy -z 20 -s myservice.. it run but site was not working. Am I missing anything? we don't want to use Arc.

Comment: You can use [slc build](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/SLC/Building+applications+with+slc) to create a tarball and then [slc deploy](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/SLC/Deploying+apps+to+Process+Manager) to deploy that tarball.